# Don't understand instance methods or instance variables RUBY

Tags: ruby

I'm still very new to Ruby and im having trouble with one of the assignments.

Genies live in tiny lamps, only coming out to grant wishes. Update your class with data indicating whether the genie is in the lamp or not. Include an enter_lamp and an exit_lamp instance method that update the genie appropriately. Whenever the genie exits the lamp, it should print " is here to consider your wish!" When the genie returns to the lamp, it should print "Goodbye for now." When first created, the genie should start off inside the lamp.

Update your driver code to test your work.

```
class Genie
  attr_accessor :name 
  attr_reader :age


    def initialize(name, age)
        @name = name
        @age = age
        @enter_lamp = enter_lamp
        @exit_lamp = exit_lamp
    end

    def exit_lamp 
        puts "#{name} is here to consider your wish!"
    end 

    def enter_lamp
        puts "Goodbye for now."
    end 

end 


anything = Genie.new("Leonardo", 85)
anything.name = "Michael"
```

Comment: What is your conrete question?

Comment: my question is how to add an exit_lamp and enter_lamp instance method. and having a driver code to run both instances. I keep getting errors which confuse me

Comment: The instance methods already exist and you have to add an instance variable, which save the state, either inside or outside the lamp. The both methods toggle the state. Any ideas?

Comment: What are the errors you are getting? I may see at least an obvious error when you use `name` in `puts "#{name} is here to consider your wish!"`. You should use `@name`, because there is no `name`in exit_lamp.

Comment: What do you mean by driver code?

Comment: @EddeAlmeida That doesn't seem correct. He has an `attr_accessor` for `:name` so the interpolation in the `puts` method calls the `attr_reader` _name_ method which returns `@name`

Comment: You are right, @BlackEnigma. I missed this fact. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Instance methods and variables are controlled by an instance of a class, and are not shared between instances. Class methods and variables are controlled by the Class, and affect all instances.

For example, an instance variable for a 'Human' object might contain age, name, hair color, or eye color as instance variables. It's something that we all have, and we all have unique values (or at least, we don't always have the same value).

So Bob is 20 with black hair, Sally is 90 and has gray hair.

If I change Bob's hair color, Sally's hair is not changed.

Contrast this to a class variable, which is shared exactly across all instances.

So Bob and Sally both have a class variable for their eyes -  because they and every other human have two.

If I wanted to change this to 3 eyes, I'd have to change human DNA (the Human class), and (in a OOP world) all humans would then have 3 eyes.

Comment: what i would like to do is when i input my driver code anything.enter_lamp, i want it to output "Goodbye for now". same for enter_lamp

Comment: Maybe im wroting the driver code wrong? i keep getting /n error

Comment: If you want it to return the string instead, remove `puts` from the enter/exit lamp methods.